# vs code cannot find module .vue and package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

With Visual Studio Code, and [automatic type acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) enabled, there are `[js] Cannot find module` errors:

- on .vue files imported in a .js file (example [here](https://github.com/francoisromain/camomile-ui/blob/master/src/app.js))
- on package.json imported in webpack.config.js (example [here](https://github.com/francoisromain/camomile-ui/blob/2a29c2e7a81415f55eb0c8fd7d1fbd0fcaadfbeb/build/webpack.config.dist.js#L11))

How is it possible to fix that? 
Thank you